# Measure instantiation + method execution time in Python

Tags: python, time, benchmarking

I have a Python class and want to measure the time it takes to instantiate the class and execute a method across numerous, e.g., 100, runs.

I noticed that the first run takes considerably longer than consecutive runs. I assume that is caused by branch prediction since the input does not change. However, I want to measure the time it takes "from scratch", i.e., without the benefit of branch prediction. Note that constructing a realistic input is difficult in this case, thus the runs have to be executed on the same input.

To tackle this, I tried creating a new object on each run and delete the old object:

```py
import time

class Myobject:

    def mymethod(self):
        """
        Does something complex.
        """
        pass

def benchmark(runs=100):
    """
    The argument runs corresponds to the number of times the benchmark is to be executed.
    """
    times_per_run = []
    r = range(runs)

    for _ in r:
        t2_start = time.perf_counter()

        # instantiation
        obj = Myobject()
        # method execution
        obj.mymethod()
        del obj

        t2_stop = time.perf_counter()

        times_per_run.append(t2_stop-t2_start)

    print(times_per_run)

benchmark(runs=10)
```

Executing this code shows that the average time per run varies significantly. The first run takes consistently longer. How do I eliminate the benefit of branch prediction when benchmarking across multiple runs?

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre] for the benchmark? The code as shown is incomplete and runs only once. It's not clear to me what you are benchmarking, nor what exactly you consider the "first run". Be aware also that there are various benchmarking libraries that avoid some pitfalls, e.g. the builtin ``timeit`` or the third-party ``pyperf``.

Comment: Note that just filling in the blanks leads to a total benchmark time of just 20-40 μs, with no trend of total/per-run time related to first/last runs.

Comment: Edited the code. One iteration of the loop corresponds to one run. Hence, the argument `runs` represents the number of of times the benchmark is to be executed. The average per run is significantly lower on 100 runs compared to 1 run, which demonstrates that the first run takes longer.

Comment: Your benchmark contains overhead for calling ``perf_counter`` and creating ``range(runs)``. This skews the timing for lower numbers – even a ``runs=0`` will take *some* time. On my machine, the overhead is about 10 times larger than a single run. The overhead error for `runs=1` vs `runs=100` is thus roughly 1100% vs 110%, and the two results are not linearly comparable.

Comment: How could calling `perf_counter` skew the time if it is consistently called twice disregarding the number of runs? Also, `runs=0` obviously takes some time. But that is not the problem. The problem is that the average per run decreases between 1 run and 100 runs which cannot be explained using your points. In other words, `runs=2` does not take double the time of `runs=1`. EDIT: edited the code such that the range is created before the `perf_counter` call.

Comment: The overhead time is *constant* but the per-run time is *linear* with ``runs``. So ``runs=2`` has only *half* the relative overhead as ``runs=1``.

Comment: Your new code reduces the overhead but it is still at about 4 times the duration of a single run. You can further reduce it by locally caching ``time.perf_counter`` but there will always be *some* overhead by the nature that function calls take time.

Comment: I see your point, now. However, the time does vary significantly between individual runs (s. new code). The first run takes longer consistently. How can this be explained?

Comment: The very first call to ``time.perf_counter()`` has some overhead for setting up the timer, which you can remove by calling ``time.perf_counter()`` once before the benchmark. The first run definitely does have some "warmup" overhead for the code itself, e.g. fetching the method bytecode (which caches it), binding it, allocating memory for all that, etc. What you can do is remove that warmup (by discarding one benchmark); what you cannot do is *replicating* the warmup for each benchmark or even each run (it goes much further than just the interpreter).

Comment: Ok, I see. This could really be it. Thank you! I think I will call the benchmark from the outside via bash or something to have the warmup time in each run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid the benefits of warmup (s. comments on post), I used the `subprocess` module to trigger the runs individually while measuring the time for each run and aggregate the results afterwards:

```py
def benchmark(runs=100):
    times_per_run = []

    command = "python3 ./myclass.py"

    for _ in range(runs):
        t1_start = time.perf_counter()
        subprocess.run([command], capture_output=True, shell=True, check=False)
        t1_stop = time.perf_counter()

        times_per_run.append(t1_stop - t1_start)

    logging.info(f"Average time per run: {sum(times_per_run) / runs}")

benchmark()
```

This yields stable results.